# Affiliation during unpaid leave?

Tags: publications, affiliation

If I take an unpaid leave from my institute to work for another institution, is it ok to put my original institution as a second affiliation on publications produced during the leave? That is regardless of the research funding source.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are "on leave," meaning that you still have an appointment at your primary institution that you can expect to return to, then yes, you may use both affiliations.  Sometimes it is explicitly noted that you are on leave from this appointment, but that depends on journal policies.

Comment: It would be great if someone can provide an example from a reputable journal.